# Build Server or local build in custom Build Task

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

In a custom MSBuild Task, I would like to perform additional validation steps if the build is occurring as part of a CI build on a TFS build server.  What would be the most robust and portable method of discovering the environment that the build is occurring in?  I don't want to have to revisit the code when the build server changes or TFS is upgraded.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a condition on the Task you wish to perform. Set the condition = true when you are building as part of a TFS build, but default it to not-set or false otherwise.

For example, in the project file where your task is executed:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DoMyTask Condition="'$(DoMyTask)'==''">false</DoMyTask>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then add the condition to your task:

```
<TaskName 
  TaskParam="Value"
  ...
  Condition="'$(DoTaskName)'=='true'" />
```

Then open your build definition and navigate to the Process tab. Under Advanced, you can add extra MSBuild arguments. Append the following (using my example property above): /p:DoMyTask=true

You can also achieve this same result by appending the '/p:DoMyTask=true' in your build process template if you will be using this across many builds all the time.

As an aside: I'm sure there are plenty of different ways to determine whether or not your build is occurring on a build machine or not. I would highly recommend you do not use 'guessing' to determine build environment as it makes for difficult diagnosing later.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in your build process template and set it for builds in central server. This way you can pass the variable to your task. If the variable is set to a specific value, then it is a build in the central server.

For more information on how to modify the build process template, follow this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx